# how to access the image which is added dynamically using jquery in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Even this question is duplicate of how to bind the dynamic elemnts still i didnt get clue for my issue.i have a code that will load the data from table using jquery (in pop-up) - dynamically. This will include the add an image for remove row operation. So i should code to remove the correspnding row when user click on that image. But my jquery flow not entering into flow when click on an image. So please help me to find the bug.

```js
$("#tab_logic").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
var tableinsp = $("#tab_logic");
$.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
  var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
  rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['parameters']);
  rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['specifications']);
  rowNew.children().eq(2).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact10" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
  rowNew.children().eq(3).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact20" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
  rowNew.children().eq(4).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact30" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
  rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact40" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
  rowNew.children().eq(6).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact50" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
  rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<img src="delete.gif" height="42" width="42" alt="idata" class="del">'); // image row
  rowNew.appendTo(tableinsp);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tab_logic").on("click", ".del", function() {
    alert("i am");
    // add code here
  });
});
```

Comment: can you pls try this :-  `$("body").on("click", "#tab_logic .del", function() {
    alert("i am");
    // add code here
  });`

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
$("body").on("click", "#tab_logic .del",
    function() {
      alert("i am"); // add code here 
});
```

Comment: is there a way to get closest tr and delete the same. $("#tab_logic").parent().remove(); doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').on('click', e => { alert('you clicked a button!') })
$(document.body).append($('<button></button>').text("I've been added from JavaScript"))
```

If you click on the button that says `I've been added from JavaScript`, no alert will pop up, I think you understood that.

So, the solution is to listen click *on the body*, and check if the *target* was a button. jQuery allows you to do it like so:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button', e => { alert("you clicked a button!") })
```

For more about [`$.on()`](http://devdocs.io/jquery/on).

Without jQuery (because sometimes it's helpful to understand how to magic happens)

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // e.target is the clicked element
    // in our case, we just want to check if the tag name is `button`
    if (e.target.nodeName != 'BUTTON') {
        return // stop the function
    }

    alert("you click a button!")
```

})

`e.target.nodeName` is always upper cased (you can call `.toLowerCase()` upon it if you want to)